# How to pause/resume thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread that running into an activity. I **don't want** that the thread continuos running when the user click the home button or, for example, the user receive a call phone.
So I want pause the thread and resume it when the user re-opens the application.
I've tried with this:

```
protected void onPause() {
  synchronized (thread) {
    try {
      thread.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
  thread.notify();
  super.onResume();
}
```

It stops the thread but don't resume it, the thread seems freezed.

I've also tried with the deprecated method `Thread.suspend()` and `Thread.resume()`, but in this case into `Activity.onPause()` the thread doesn't stop.

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use `wait()` and `notifyAll()` properly using a lock.

Sample code:

```
class YourRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Object mPauseLock;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private boolean mFinished;

    public YourRunnable() {
        mPauseLock = new Object();
        mPaused = false;
        mFinished = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!mFinished) {
            // Do stuff.

            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                while (mPaused) {
                    try {
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call this on pause.
     */
    public void onPause() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call this on resume.
     */
    public void onResume() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = false;
            mPauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It runs, thanks! But why I must call the `wait` and `notifyAll` methods on an Object into the thread and not directly on the thread-object?

Comment: Try reading this -> http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/memory.doc.html

Comment: (1) Is it possible to use the above code within IntentService instead of Runnable? (2) why is it not mPauseLock.notify() instead of notifyAll()?

Comment: Thanks for this, however whenever I run this for my app it exits with FATAL EXCEPTION: THREAD-10 and a null pointer exception.

Comment: Where do I set the delay... how fast the runnable will 'run' per turn?

Comment: I had studied this a time long ago on Vijay Garg's book "Concurrent and Distributed Computing in Java", but somehow I had forgotten what I had to do to pause a looping thread, but had somehow forgotten the technique. Your code is a textbook example of how it should be done, and properly!

Comment: what if  `// Do Stuff` consist of running a while loop for a limited seconds, like `int i=100;`  , `while (i>0){Thread.sleep(500); i--;}`   . how will the pause mechanism work then?

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code it will work

```
Thread thread=null;
```

OnResume()

```
  public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  if(thread == null){
  thread = new Thread()
  {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {

              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  };

  thread.start();
      }
  }
```

onPause()

```
@Override
 public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
if(thread != null){
Thread moribund = thread;
thread = null;
moribund.interrupt();
}
}
```

Comment: This looks simple.. are there problems that could arise from this?  Why not just thread.interrupt?  Is it nullified first to kill other references to it or something?

Comment: well, it is not pausing/resuming. It is destroying/recreating. Can be performance killer on android, which has Auto Screen Rotation turned on, and user will be continuously shaking the device causing screen to autorotate.