# Android - pause and continue thread

Tags: java, android

In my Activity I create a Thread for multiply objects and "save" them to a hashmap. Is it possible to pause just a single thread of the hasmap and continue it?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  Thread oThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          while (true) {
            // doing some work
          }
        }
  }
  oThread.start();
  aThreads.put(name, oThread);

}

public void anyMethod(){
  // here I want to start and continue a thread
  aThreads.get(name).stop();
  aThreads.get(name).resume();
}
```

But .stop() and .resume() aren't working :/ any suggestions?

Comment: Check this answer maybe this is what you trying to achieve : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6776463/665823

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776327/how-to-pause-resume-thread-in-android/6776463#6776463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean variable to control the thread exection.

ie.

```
 while(!isThreadRunning){

...your statements
}
```

Once you are moving out of the screen in OnPause method make the variable false/true based on your usage to stop the thread execution.And you have to take care of the persisting hashmap.