# Android FTP download pause/resume

Tags: java, android, download, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm working on an Android project that requires FTP download to be paused/resumed.

Here is the code I use for FTP connection:

```
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(25000);
ftpClient.login("login", "password");
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/audio");
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

then I start download:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;
totalRead = 0;

if (localFileSize > 0) {
    ftpClient.setRestartOffset(localFileSize);
    ftpClient.restart(localFileSize);
}

InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(fileName);

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
    totalRead += bytesRead;
    outputStream.write(bytesArray, (int) localFileSize, bytesRead);
}

success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
```

and I try to pause using `abort` like this:

```
if (ftpClient.abort()) {
   //connection aborted!;
}
```

But it seems that `abort` doesn't work while there is an active download as mentioned here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-419

**Is there any way I can perform pause/resume for FTP downloads in Android?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same `AsyncTask` for connect, download and abort operations:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
   int command = params.length > 0 ? params[0] : 0;
   switch (command) {
   case CONNECT:
       connect();
       break;
   case DOWNLOAD:
       download();
       break;
   case PAUSE:
       abortConnection();
       break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

To make sure there is only one task running each time I used **Singleton design pattern**

```
public static FtpConnectTask getInstance(FTPClientWrapper ftpClient) {
   if (instance != null) {
      if (instance.getStatus().name().toLowerCase().equals("running"){
         instance.cancel(true);
      }
      if (instance.getStatus().name().toLowerCase().equals("finished")) {
          // task finished!
      }
   }
   instance = new FtpConnect(uiListener, ftpClientW);
   return instance;
}
```

This is code of `download()` method:

> we look for local file size each time the download starts, then we use this size as starting point

```
//create local file
File localFile = new File(outDir, FILE_NAME));
// get file size if the file exists
long localFileSize = localFile.length();   
//retrieve file from server
try {
  OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile, true));
  byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
  int bytesRead;
  int totalRead = (int) localFileSize;
  ftpClient.restart(localFileSize);
  InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(REMOTE_FILE);

  while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
     totalRead += bytesRead;
     outputStream.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
  // break the loop when AsyncTask is cancelled
     if(isCancelled()){
        break;
     }
  }
  if (ftpClient.completePendingCommand()) {
     // Task completed!
  }

  inputStream.close();
  outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is code of `abortConnection()`

```
if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
   try {
      if (ftpClient.abort()) {
         // Connection aborted!
      }
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
} else {
   // Not connected!
}
```

> To resume your download just call `download()` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to pause the download only (as opposite to abort/reconnect/resume), then all you need to do, is temporarily pause the `while` loop that writes to the data connection stream.

See [How to pause/resume thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6776327/850848)

Comment: thank you for your answer @Martin Prikryl, I tried it and found the download still going in background until the file completes.

Comment: How can it continue, if you do not provide data to the stream? All it can possibly do, is to finish uploading a buffered data that you wrote to the stream previously. But it cannot continue until the file completes. Where it would get the data from?